# Python-put multiply character between int and string

Tags: python, function, math, graph

I'm going to create a program to draw a linear function graph. Let's say that user input something like this:

```
3x-2x+2
```

I want to change it to:

```
3*x-2*x+2
```

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that using regular expressions:

```
re.sub(r"(?<=\d)x","*x","3x-2x+2")
```

This looks for a digit followed by `x`, and inserts a `*` before `x` (not consuming the leading digit - lookbehind)

If you don't know the letter but want to do it for `a`, `b` ... use lookbehind+lookahead like this:

```
re.sub(r"(?<=\d)(?=[a-zA-Z])","*","3a-2b+2")
```

(my first answer was lazy, I didn't use lookahead because I knew that we were looking for `x`)

Comment: That was what I was looking for. Thank you so much !

Comment: Is there a way to make this do it for every letter?